# jquery + instagram + image montage

Tags: jquery-plugins, instagram

I'm having trouble integrating to jquery plugins.  http://potomak.github.com/jquery-instagram/ and http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/

I can get the image montage to work no problem OR the instagram photos to load but I can't make the instagram photos into the image montage.  I am calling the same div class for both functions.

Comment: Are you getting any error on console? You can check the error using inspect element or firebug. The error message would help in debugging the issue better.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if they are overriding some function like window.onLoad() or setting a timer that is also used by the other?

I have one kind of instagram image loader running at www.pixomundo.com feel free to look at the code there.